# QuickBooks SDK PurchaseOrderAdd.RefNumber.SetValue()

Tags: sdk, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

On December 4, 2013, the Quickbooks Pro 2013 SDK appears to have changed its behavior.

I have issued this command for years: 
SalesOrderValue = returned Sales Order Reference Value from creating a Sales Order

PurchaseOrderAdd.RefNumber.SetValue(SalesOrderValue)

Quickbooks is no longer respecting this command.  The created Purchase Order Reference Number is now the next consecutive Sales order Number, not the number that I tell it to use.

I have rebuilt the Quickbooks Data File.  It did not help (hoping it was a bad index)

Any idea on what has happened?  More importantly, is there is a fix to restore this functionality?

Comment: What release of QB are you running?  Did you just update QB or was QB updated around this date? (You might need to do an F2 in QB and then look at what versions have accessed QB.)

Answer (score 0):

Completely ripping off **'user3150303'** else but we installed SDK 13.0, and changed version number to 12 and it worked.

I had the same issue, only using QBFC. I fixed it by changing the line

```
requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 2, 0)
```

to

```
requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0)
```